# C++/Cli iTextSharp нумерация страниц при создании документа

Tags: itextsharp

Как в C++/Cli используя библиотеку iTextSharp проставить нумерацию страниц (по центру) при создании PDF документа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

использование

```
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph(); 
preface.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

См. Константы ALIGN_ * в интерфейсе Element для получения более возможных значений.